# I have javascript I use to set a hidden value in a form, how do I show an error message for the associated hidden attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a view which has a div at the top that shows a list of images, then a form at the bottom:

```
%div{ id: 'how-soon' }
  %ul
    - %w( now week month browsing ).each do |hs|
      %li{ class: 'inactive', id: hs }=image_tag "how-soon/#{hs}.jpg"

= simple_form_for @employer_signup, :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'home'), method: :post do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.hidden_field :how_soon

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, 'Join Now'
```

When a user clicks one of the images in the `#how-soon` div this coffeescript sets a hidden value in the form:

```
$("#how-soon > ul > li").click ->
  $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('inactive active')
  $(this).toggleClass('inactive active')
  $('#employer_signup_how_soon').val($(this).attr('id'))
```

The attribute that is adjusted in the form, `:how_soon` is validated by its parent model for presence, `validates :how_soon, presence: true`

If the form is submitted without a value for `:how_soon` the form is re-displayed and I do not see the specific `value missing` error because the field is hidden.

A typical solution to this seems to be to put the errors into the errors of another attribute and display them there, but I have no other attributes from this model being displayed that are visible, so I cannot display the errors that way.  I would do this with something like:

```
after_validation :validate_how_soon

protected

def validate_how_soon
  if errors[:how_soon].present?
    errors[:how_soon].each { |message| errors.add :first_name, message }
  end
end
```

**Bonus content (may not be needed to solve my problem):**

While I simplified the code above, I'm actually rendering a form using a form object that is ultimately used to create two objects, a `User` and a `Listing` (think job listing).  The attributes related to `Listing` are all hidden values filled in by the user clicking the pictures they want and having the corresponding values set via jquery in the form.  The `User` attributes are all present.  Here's the weird bit that *may* be pertinent to my issue:

When I only have errors for visible attributes (which happen to all be `User` attributes) the errors are displayed on their attributes appropriately.  However, if I have errors on the visible attributes *and* errors on the hidden attributes none of the errors for the visible attributes are shown at all, I just get the generic `Please review the problems below:` notice at the top of the form.

Like I said, this "bonus content" may not actually help with the problem, but I thought I'd leave it here anyway.

Comment: If the hidden field is populated by your JS, then how can the case of it having no value even occur? (If filling it is dependent of the user interacting with other fields, then _their_ validation should be set to fail if the right action to trigger filling of the hidden field is not undertaken.)

Comment: @CBroe The way I have it set up the hidden value is nil until they 'click' one of the images.  The clickable images don't have validation themselves because I am (and was hoping to continue) relying on the simpleform helper to create my form with error notifications, while the images + javascript I'm using is just a simple widget I created to populate the hidden-field's value.

Answer (score 0):

By submitting a form to your Rails backend, whether it's hidden or not, the validations will still return errors if you don't fill in the correct data

You can handle hidden fields the same as "normal" ones:

```
validates :how_soon, presence: true
```

Does this not bring back the error you need?

---

You'll have to include something like this in your form:

```
<% if resource.errors.full_messages.present? %>
        <!-- Errors -->
    <ul>
         <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

If you let us know the response of the errors hash, we'll be in a much better position to help resolve the iissue directly!